# iframe working in all systems except on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, laravel, iframe

I have a modal and in that modal I'm loading an iframe. The modal works perfectly in every device EXCEPT on ios (All browsers). What is happening in ios is that the modal isn't even opening and the elements nearby lose their clickability. Here is my modal.

When it is like this it is fine even in ios.

```
<a href="" data-modal="#modal" class="modal__trigger">Modal 1</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal modal__bg" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__dialog">
        <div class="modal__content">
            <h1>Modal</h1>
            <p>Content here</p>

            <!-- modal close button -->
            <a href="" class="modal__close demo-close">
                <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/></svg>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the moment I add an iframe inside that modal like this

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal modal__bg" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__dialog">
        <div class="modal__content">
            <h1>Modal</h1>
            <iframe src="{{action('BehaviourController@positiveIncidences', [$grade->grade_id, $day])}}"></iframe>

            <!-- modal close button -->
            <a href="" class="modal__close demo-close">
                <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/></svg>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works on every device apart from ios. The modal stops being clickable at all in ios. And I can't seem to establish where the problem is.

Here is the JS to initialize the modal:

```
var Modal = (function() {

var trigger = $qsa('.modal__trigger'); // what you click to activate the modal
 var modals = $qsa('.modal'); // the entire modal (takes up entire window)
 var modalsbg = $qsa('.modal__bg'); // the entire modal (takes up entire window)
var content = $qsa('.modal__content'); // the inner content of the modal
var closers = $qsa('.modal__close'); // an element used to close the modal
var w = window;
var isOpen = false;
var contentDelay = 400; // duration after you click the button and wait for the content to show
var len = trigger.length;


function $qsa(el) {
return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}

var getId = function(event) {

// event.preventDefault();
var self = this;
// get the value of the data-modal attribute from the button
var modalId = self.dataset.modal;
var len = modalId.length;
// remove the '#' from the string
var modalIdTrimmed = modalId.substring(1, len);
// select the modal we want to activate
var modal = document.getElementById(modalIdTrimmed);
// execute function that creates the temporary expanding div
makeDiv(self, modal);
};

var makeDiv = function(self, modal) {

var fakediv = document.getElementById('modal__temp');

/**
 * if there isn't a 'fakediv', create one and append it to the button that was
 * clicked. after that execute the function 'moveTrig' which handles the animations.
 */

if (fakediv === null) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'modal__temp';
  self.appendChild(div);
  moveTrig(self, modal, div);
 }
};

var moveTrig = function(trig, modal, div) {
var trigProps = trig.getBoundingClientRect();
var m = modal;
var mProps = m.querySelector('.modal__content').getBoundingClientRect();
var transX, transY, scaleX, scaleY;
var xc = w.innerWidth / 2;
var yc = w.innerHeight / 2;

// this class increases z-index value so the button goes overtop the other buttons
trig.classList.add('modal__trigger--active');

// these values are used for scale the temporary div to the same size as the modal
scaleX = mProps.width / trigProps.width;
scaleY = mProps.height / trigProps.height;

scaleX = scaleX.toFixed(3); // round to 3 decimal places
scaleY = scaleY.toFixed(3);


// these values are used to move the button to the center of the window
transX = Math.round(xc - trigProps.left - trigProps.width / 2);
transY = Math.round(yc - trigProps.top - trigProps.height / 2);

    // if the modal is aligned to the top then move the button to the center-y of the modal instead of the window
if (m.classList.contains('modal--align-top')) {
  transY = Math.round(mProps.height / 2 + mProps.top - trigProps.top - trigProps.height / 2);
}


    // translate button to center of screen
    trig.style.transform = 'translate(' + transX + 'px, ' + transY + 'px)';
    trig.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + transX + 'px, ' + transY + 'px)';
    // expand temporary div to the same size as the modal
    div.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')';
    div.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')';


    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            open(m, div);
        });
    }, contentDelay);

};

var open = function(m, div) {

if (!isOpen) {
  // select the content inside the modal
  var content = m.querySelector('.modal__content');
  // reveal the modal
  m.classList.add('modal--active');
  // reveal the modal content
  content.classList.add('modal__content--active');

  /**
   * when the modal content is finished transitioning, fadeout the temporary
   * expanding div so when the window resizes it isn't visible ( it doesn't
   * move with the window).
   */

  content.addEventListener('transitionend', hideDiv, false);

  isOpen = true;
}

function hideDiv() {
  // fadeout div so that it can't be seen when the window is resized
  div.style.opacity = '0';
  content.removeEventListener('transitionend', hideDiv, false);
 }
 };

var close = function(event) {

    // event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

var target = event.target;
var div = document.getElementById('modal__temp');

/**
 * make sure the modal__bg or modal__close was clicked, we don't want to be able to click
 * inside the modal and have it close.
 */

if (isOpen && target.classList.contains('modal__bg') || 
target.classList.contains('modal__close')) {

  // make the hidden div visible again and remove the transforms so it 
  scales back to its original size
  div.style.opacity = '1';
  div.removeAttribute('style');

        /**
        * iterate through the modals and modal contents and triggers to remove their active classes.
  * remove the inline css from the trigger to move it back into its original position.
        */

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            modals[i].classList.remove('modal--active');
            content[i].classList.remove('modal__content--active');
            trigger[i].style.transform = 'none';
    trigger[i].style.webkitTransform = 'none';
            trigger[i].classList.remove('modal__trigger--active');
        }

  // when the temporary div is opacity:1 again, we want to remove it from the dom
        div.addEventListener('transitionend', removeDiv, false);

  isOpen = false;

}

function removeDiv() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      // remove the temp div from the dom with a slight delay so the animation looks good
      div.remove();
    });
  }, contentDelay - 50);
}

 };

 var bindActions = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  trigger[i].addEventListener('click', getId, false);
  closers[i].addEventListener('click', close, false);
  modalsbg[i].addEventListener('click', close, false);
 }
 };

var init = function() {
bindActions();
};

 return {
 init: init
 };

 }());

Modal.init();
```

Comment: What's the iframe source - same or different origin, HTTP/HTTPS, restricted by X-FRAME-OPTIONS or any other headers, ...? Got browser console access on an iOS device to check for errors?

Comment: You can debug an iOS device's browser using Safari on a Mac ("Develop" menu) if you have one to test.

Comment: The iframe is from the same domain and it is http, it is not restricted. I have a windows machine not a mac. Is there a way to debug ios on windows?